# Can't see the way to depict chess deck on PyQT5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a list with 64 objects. The empty cells are 0. Other cells are objects of class Checker. I can't undarstand, how I can create a big deck and cut it into 64 small objects on which I will be able to post my objects. I can create 64 buttons connected to each object, but I don't thing, that is nice idea. Can you give me some ideas ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [qgraphicscene](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html) for your deck and [qgraphicsgridlayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsgridlayout.html) to arrange